# What is different? [the something of one's choice & the choice of one's something.]

Tags: idioms

I have read two links gotten some feedback from another forum.

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-something-of-your-choice

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/choice_1?q=choice+
[image]

https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/286514-the-something-of-your-choice-the-choice-of-your-something

According to the feedback, both structures are not the same.

> the something of one's choice

> the choice of one's something.

Could you tell what is different? I still don't understand why they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone on the other forum pointed out, *the choice of your [something]* is not really idiomatic English.

*The [something] of your choice* has a positive meaning - the one you have specially chosen as your favourite.

*Your choice of [something]* **may** be used in a negative sense, as in "I don't like his choice of friends".

*The choice of his friends* would mean 'what his friends have chosen'. It's possible to invent a context in which you might say that, but it's not a very likely expression.